# mysqli_query doesn't return false when no record was found

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

If I run this code, the if-clause won't return false even though the data record doesn't exist in the database `myDB` in table `myTable`. I don't know what's wrong..

```
// MySQLi-Connection...

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `myDB`.`myTable` WHERE `itemtype` = 'comment' AND `itemID` = 3");
if ($result) {
echo "record found!";
} else {
echo "record not found!";
}
```

The record with `itemID` = 3 doesn't exist, but my if-clause says that the $result returns true..

Comment: print_r($result) then try if (!empty($result)) {

Comment: `Returns FALSE on failure.` (http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) An empty dataset is not a failed query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries
mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries 
mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
```

[#Reference PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

You can use

```
$result = $mysqli->query("YOUR QUERY")); 
if($result->num_rows){
 // Records Found
}else{
 // Empty Result
}
```

Comment: $result->num_rows is the best solution for my problem (i am using multiple datasets) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its much logical to use [**`mysqli_num_rows`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) here:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `myDB`.`myTable` WHERE `itemtype` = 'comment' AND `itemID` = 3");
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'record found';
} else {
    echo 'query is ok but no results found';
}
```

You can't put a mysqli_result object in your if since it will still evaluate as TRUE even if it yields 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP if statement will evaluate to TRUE, as an empty mysql results set does not mean it is a failed query. The query ran ok, and mysql retrieved 0 rows, hence $result evaluates to true.

To check if a valid row has been retrieved, try:

```
if ( ! empty($result) ) { 
  echo "record found!";
} else {
  echo "record not found!";
}
```